# Steps to connect Angular4 to a Database (Oracle)

Tags: database, oracle, angular, rest

Actually I've to connect my Angular project to a database to access some data. But I don't know how.

Should I write a REST API to do it? If yes, how can I connect my REST API to my project?

Which steps should I follow?

Thanks

Comment: REST is the industry standard for this sort of thing. There are many ways to implement REST. Which one fits you best will depend on many things. At this point probably Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

The angular application will be your "front" application. To store and fetch data
from a database you'll need a "back" application that will provide URLS for your angular App to call.

A simple back can be done using Laravel and OCI 8 connector in order to query ORACLE database. The backend would be in PHP which is a common solution but might not fit your needs.

Set up your laravel project : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4

Install OCI8 module to connect to your oracle database : https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8

Then follow laravel's guidelines to set up URLs that will be callable by your front application in Angular4.